# How to make Youtube serve videos in h264 in Safari instead of VP9

Tags: safari, video, youtube, h.264

So if remember correctly with Safari 15 Youtube started to serve videos in VP9 instead of h264 as it was before. Which enabled resolutions over 1080p but disabled GPU decoding. Which is producing quite a sizeable load especially on older CPUs.

On Chrome and Firefox we have h264ify (or Enhanced h264ify) extensions which enables you to choose what codec to serve your videos in but what about Safari? Had anyone found a solution for this particular inconvenience?

Comment: How did you learn about which codecs YouTube is serving you videos in?