# Disable hardware acceleration in Safari (for YouTube)

Tags: macos, safari, monterey, youtube

Nowadays when I watch YouTube videos, my poor 2015 MacBook's fans are louder than the video.

I think that's because of YouTube's high GPU usage, and I guess that YouTube's hardware acceleration is a new(ish) feature (of either YouTube or Safari)

How can I disable that? I don't want YouTube to use any GPU

Neither Firefox nor Google Chrome cause overheating. Neither of them seem to have any GPU usage according to Activity Monitor. Safari's youtube.com tab has 4-10% GPU usage according to Activity Monitor.

Comment: This [existing question about Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/461973/119271) addresses the problem you’re having.   Try using a Browser and an extension ([Firefox h264ify](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/461973/119271))  that forces YouTube to serve vides in H.264

Comment: @Allan I don't have the problem at all in Firefox in the first place. I'm not sure how to begin debugging it

Comment: This does seem a little backwards.  By *disabling* your GPU, it will put all of the load on the CPU resulting in higher CPU usage and higher CPU temps.  I’ve abandoned Safari a long time ago mostly, but not exclusively, due to performance issues.  Use FF or Edge for your video consumption  needs.

Comment: @Allan my GPU just seems so much worse than my CPU that I'd rather everything is performed on the CPU, e.g. my recent Minecraft questions - when an app uses 4% GPU, it causes my laptop to have max fans and be burning hot. When all that processing is handled by the CPU, the laptop may as well be sleeping it's so peaceful

Comment: I have not had any problems with Safari until recently, the last few months. I guess either YouTube or Safari changed, trying to use the GPU to play videos